# Angular 9 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

What I am trying to accomplish is to see if a user session is already there and if so log them in. But I am having issues with how to execute this properly. It's most likely to do with code execution order, but I do not understand what to do to solve this. Perhaps async?

Getting:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Sidebar.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(res => {
  if (res){
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
  } else {
   
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }
});
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
      get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    const authToken = this.cookieService.get('cookiehere');
    // console.log(authToken);
    if (authToken) {
      this.getUserBySession(authToken).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);

        return of(true);
      }, error => {
        return of(false);
      });
    }
    if (!authToken){
      console.log('No token found!');
      return of(false);
    }
  }


  getUserBySession(session) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiPrefix}/auth/get_user_by_session?session=${session}`, { headers: this.headers })
      .pipe(map((res: any) => {
        if (res.user) {
          this.currentUser = res.user;
          return res;
        } else {
          return res;
        }}));
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subscribing to an observable here but you're not returning an observable from the getter. The `return of(true)` you have there returns from inside the `subscribe` callback, not the getter. You would have to change it to return the original observable from the `getUserBySession` function

```
get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  const authToken = this.cookieService.get('vmkr');
  if (authToken) {
    return this.getUserBySession(authToken).pipe(
      map(() => true),
      catchError(() => of(false))
    );
  } else {
    console.log('No token found!');
    return of(false);
  }
}
```

Though I imagine a getter here could cause problems with multiple subscriptions somewhere down the line.