# Angular 11 Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular

```
public getPosts(): Observable<Employee[]>{
         
          this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:84/api/User').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        });
        return;
      }
```

error through from this function
Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

```
public getEmployees(){   
   

    this.appService.getPosts().subscribe(data => {
      this.employees = data; 
      this.employees.shift();
    }); 

     
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 9 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203985/angular-9-typeerror-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Your service is not correct. You need to provide Observable data to caller.

```
public getPosts(): Observable<Employee[]>{
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:84/api/User');
 }
```

Comment: Note that in this case you loose the console logging part of the service.

Comment: thank you for your answer. your answer is working but an interesting error. when i call this url in post man in return 3 records. but getPosts() return only 2 records. first record omitted. in this console.log(data); . what is the issue. i try this for last 2 days. please help

Comment: @VinodJohn Probably because you call ```shift``` method which removes first element from array.

Comment: @VinodJohn No problem, please accept my answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in your service.

- You are returning undefined in your `getPosts()` method (`return;` in last line).
- You are subscribing in your `getPosts()`
  thus returning a `Subscription` instead of an `Observable`

If you want to console log in your `getPost` function you can pipe the `observable` and use `tap` operator for your purpose.

```
public getPosts(): Observable<Employee[]> {
  return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:84/api/User').pipe(
    tap((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. your answer is working but an interesting error in it. when i call this url in post man it returns 3 records. but getPosts() return only 2 records. first record omitted. in this console.log(data); . what is the issue. i try this for last 2 days. please help

Comment: That's due to the shift which basically removes first element of array.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning nothing (`undefined`) from your `getPosts` method.

Change it to:

```
return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:84/api/User').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        });
```

(Remove the `return;`)

EDIT: there is also another issue with your code, it won't return an `Observable` but rather a `Subscription`.

You should furthermore change it to:

```
return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:84/api/User').pipe(
   tap(data => console.log(data))
);
```

`tap` is a method dedicated to run side effect and keep the original value emitted.

Comment: there is still an issue due to which  `getEmployees()` will not work, the service function is returning a subscription and not an `observable`

Comment: Ah right, haven't catch that. I'll update my answer, thanks :)